# Using a Grid as an ItemsHost

Tags: wpf, grid, itemspresenter

I would like to use a Grid as an ItemsHost but none of the items appear in their bound (column, row) positions. How can I make this work? As a simple example:

XAML

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataSet}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="{Binding Col}" Grid.Row="{Binding Row}" Text="{Binding Text}"   />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsItemsHost="True">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition />
                                <RowDefinition />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.Style>
</ItemsControl>
```

Codebehind

```
Class Window1 

    Private myTestData As TestData

    Public Sub New()
        ' This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        myTestData = New TestData()
        Me.DataContext = myTestData
    End Sub

End Class

Class TestData

    Private myDataSet As List(Of DataPoint)
    Public Property DataSet() As List(Of DataPoint)
        Get
            Return myDataSet
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of DataPoint))
            myDataSet = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New()
        Me.DataSet = New List(Of DataPoint)
        For x As Integer = 0 To 1
            For y As Integer = 0 To 1
                Me.DataSet.Add(New DataPoint(x, y, "Column " + x.ToString + ", Row " + y.ToString))
            Next
        Next
    End Sub

End Class

Class DataPoint

    Private myRow As Integer
    Public Property Row() As Integer
        Get
            Return myRow
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            myRow = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private myCol As Integer
    Public Property Col() As Integer
        Get
            Return myCol
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            myCol = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private myText As String
    Public Property Text() As String
        Get
            Return myText
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            myText = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer, ByVal name As String)
        Me.Row = y
        Me.Col = x
        Me.Text = name
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you're using an `ItemsControl`, a container is generated for each item. That container (an instance of `ContentPresenter` for a plain old `ItemsControl`) wraps the `TextBlock`, and is a direct child of the `Grid`. Therefore, the `Grid` never even sees the `Column` and `Row` properties on the `TextBlock` because it's looking instead at the container.

You can solve this by setting an `ItemContainerStyle` that binds the appropriate properties for the container:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Column}"/>
        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Row}"/>
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible workaround: if you use [UniformGrid](http://www.dotnet-blog.com/index.php/2008/06/25/uniformgrid-the-simple-grid/), you may not need to specify the rows and columns.