# Can I access ItemsHost of ItemsControl using reflection?

Tags: c#, wpf, reflection, datagrid, wpf-controls

I'm creating custom `ItemsControl` that is derived from `DataGrid`. I need to access ItemsHost that is the `Panel` that actually holds rows of `DataGrid`. I have seen som ugly tricks to do that but I consider them worse then using reflection.
So can I access ItemsHost using reflection ? And how ?

Comment: Are you talking about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/691379/using-a-grid-as-an-itemshost

Comment: not exactly. See my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes I can. It is simple - I've just created property in class inheriting from `DataGrid`:

```
protected Panel ItemsHost {
    get {
        return (Panel) typeof (MultiSelector).InvokeMember("ItemsHost",
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance,
            null, this, null);
    }
}
```

It works like a charm :). I can get the value of `ItemsHost` internal property of the `ItemsControl` class. This way I can access any non-protected properties.

Comment: I have no idea what this does or why this works, but for sure it does work with my ItemsControl :)

Comment: You could use `typeof(ItemsControl)` instead of `typeof(MultiSelector)`, that would work for all `ItemsControls` then.

Answer (score 0):

If you're a fan of [@rasto's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5061947), but you're concerned about the performance of reflection, this implementation uses [expression trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/) to create a strongly typed `Func<ItemsControl, Panel>`.  You incur the reflection cost only once.  You can also wrap it up in a handy extension method...

```
public static class ItemsControlExtensions
{

    private static readonly Lazy<Func<ItemsControl, Panel?>> getItemsHost
        = new (CreateGetItemsHostLambda);
    
    private static Func<ItemsControl, Panel?> CreateGetItemsHostLambda()
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type: typeof(ItemsControl));

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<ItemsControl, Panel>>(
            body: Expression.Property(
                expression: parameter, 
                property: typeof(ItemsControl).GetProperty(
                    name: "ItemsHost",
                    bindingAttr: BindingFlags.NonPublic 
                        | BindingFlags.GetProperty 
                        | BindingFlags.Instance
                )!
            ),
            parameter
        ).Compile();
    }
    
    public static Panel? GetItemsPanel(this ItemsControl itemsControl) 
        => getItemsHost.Value(itemsControl);

}
```