# What is the use of Type.InvokeMember

Tags: wpf, typeof, virtualizingstackpanel, invokemember

Iam working in a WPF Application and in one place I had to use this piece of code to get the reference to a VirtualizingStackPanel.

Following is the piece of code,

```
VirtualizingStackPanel vsp = (VirtualizingStackPanel)obj.InvokeMember("_itemsHost", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, content, null);

vsp.SetVerticalOffset(_SomeSelectedIndex);
```

Can someone explain what exactly this lines do and what are those binding flags ?

Comment: look here for BindingFlags http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: here is about what Type.InvokeMember do http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66btctbe(v=vs.110).aspx  with exapmles

Comment: Thanks. It helped. here's one more source to get the complete idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056728/can-i-access-itemshost-of-itemscontrol-using-reflection

Comment: And VirtualizingStackPanel.setVerticalOffset() Scrolls the items to a specific index.